# In one powershell terminal I can make aws workdocs calls but I can't in a different powershell terminal. why?

Tags: powershell, aws-cli

I am new to using the aws cli. I am not the aws cloud-ops admin so I don't have direct access to my security setup.  All I know is that I've been given an Access Key and a Security Key to use for making calls.

I am writing in powershell.  I have one terminal that's been opened for a while. It's where I've been experimenting.  In that terminal, I've been able to make any call I need.

However, if I open a new powershell terminal, I cannot make any calls to workdocs.  I am able to call "aws s3" to see buckets.  I am able to call "aws sts get-caller-identity" so I think it knows who I am. I have a profile called 'noob' that I try to use but it doesn't seem to matter.  I have called

aws configure

to set my configuration in the new terminal (even though the defaults indicate the values are already correct).

I'm wondering if there's some call I need to make to initialize my session or something in the new terminal?  If not, any ideas what could be the issue?

Thanks in advance.

I have compared which versions of aws each terminal is using. They are the same.
I have compared environment variables in both.  Neither has hardly any AWS variables, and the ones they do have are the same.
I have tried using aws sts to get a session token and setting environment variables as well. Still no luck.